# How to copy waveform of audio file in ios?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-audio, waveform, ezaudio

I m going to develop audio track editing app in ios.

I've created waveform of audio file already. And going to implement "copy" feature of selected waveform.

For this, I've get part data of NSData (audio file's) and draw waveform again with copied part data.

This formal way cant provide high speed to draw waveform for each actions (paste, delete).

So my questions is what is the best way to edit audio track ?

I will appreciate if anyone let me know similar open source link or blog link.

Thanks in advice

Comment: From how you use the term "waveform" it is not certain what you mean. A buffer containing audio samples? Something else?  Where did you get them from? Whatever has to do with _real time audio_ must be fast. In your place, I'd rely on **C** for critical code, and use Objective-C for interface.

Comment: "waveform" what I meant is a buffer containing audio samples.